# entity produce classNotFound exception in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

guys i am trying to make a project that has hibernate, spring MVC and spring security ... but when mapping the entity it produces classNotFound exception
... here is my code

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
 <context:annotation-config />
 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*" />

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

**spring-database.xml**

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">

  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="root" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.mkyong.users.model.User</value>
    <value>com.mkyong.users.model.UserRole</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="userDao" class="com.mkyong.users.dao.UserDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.mkyong.users.service.MyUserDetailsService">
  <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>

 <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
  <tx:attributes>
   <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
   <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true" />
   <tx:method name="*" />
  </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>

 <aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="userServicePointCut"
   expression="execution(* com.mkyong.users.service.*Service.*(..))" />
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServicePointCut" />
 </aop:config>

</beans>
```

the exception is

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mkyong.users.model.User
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:288)
```

any help whould be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with change SessionFactory bean configuration to this:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mkyong.users.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```